# elasticsearch-rails how to write query for search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch-rails

I am using elasticsearch-rails and elasticsearch-model gem for searching words in my rails app.

Here is my model article.rb where I want to search to take place:

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

  def self.search(query)
    __elasticsearch__.search(
      {
        query: {
          multi_match: {
            query: query,
            fuzziness: 2,
            fields: ['title^10', 'text']
          }
        },
        highlight: {
          pre_tags: ['<em>'],
          post_tags: ['</em>'],
          fields: {
            title: {},

          }
        }
      }
    )
  end
end
```

Here is my model controller search_controller.rb

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  def search
    if params[:q].nil?
      @articles = []
    else
      @articles = Article.search params[:q]
      logger.info "LocationController.add_locations called with params: #{@articles.records.each_with_hit { |record, hit| puts "* #{record.title}: #{hit._score}" }}"
    end
  end
end
```

I am getting search results. 
But my question is :
If I search for "John team".

```
Articles.search('John team').records.records
```

I get multiple records with perfect match 'john team' and some matches related to 'john' or 'team'.

but I want , if 'john team' is perfectly match in my database the result should only john team.I don't want another records.but if 'john team' is not present I want another results related to 'john' or 'team' both keywords.

example:

```
Article.search('John team').records.records
responce: ('john team', 'team joy', 'John cena')
```

But I want

```
   Article.search('John team').records.records
    responce: ('john team')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to match both the words and not any single word

```
  def self.search(query)
    __elasticsearch__.search(
      {
        query: {
          multi_match: {
            query:{ match: {content: {query: query, operator: "and" }}},
            fuzziness: 2,
            fields: ['title^10', 'text']
          }
        },
        highlight: {
          pre_tags: ['<em>'],
          post_tags: ['</em>'],
          fields: {
            title: {},

          }
        }
      }
    )
  end
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response.I tried this one I got

Comment: database_timezone option must be :utc or :local
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_parsing_exception","reason":"No fields specified for multi_match query","index":"talents","line":1,"col":94}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query_fetch","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"talents","node":"M_Xg7KxeQNiYaB8XPphFrQ","reason":{"type":"query_parsing_exception","reason":"No fields specified for multi_match query","index":"talents","line":1,"col":94}}]},"status":400}